# Custom workflow action for copying document across site sub site

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

i want to create custom workflow action for SharePoint designer workflow  which will copy documents across sites. i want to deploy this action on SharePoint online.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Flow for this kind of tasks in Office 365 as it's the new trend in doing these things. You can create a new item anywhere, when an item is added to any list. You can check some templates you can start from here:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?q=create+item

To do it using workflows in O365, you would use REST to create an item in the desired list, an example here to help you out:

http://mysharepointinsight.blogspot.ca/2013/05/using-sharepoint-rest-services-from.html

Comment: thanks for answer but my current functionality does not support in given flow template.

Comment: If you need to make it inside the workflow itself, in O365, I would go for REST call to create an item in the desired list. I'll update my answer based on that

Comment: rest call copyTo does not provide any help while copying documents across site. it will work within a site across document library.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html

Comment: no help, as he want to fetch a data from  file byte by byte, this does not supported in SharePoint designer workflow.

Comment: I haven't used dictionaries and looping in workflows yet, but am thinking "out loud" here, I would try loops with dictionaries along with this way to achieve it